# Is it possible to override SensorManager frequency when the screen is off?

Tags: android, intervals, accelerator, sensormanager

I'm working on a simple app that plays a sound when the Accelerometer hits a certain value.
When the screen is on, there is no problem. The frequency at which the accelerator runs is fine.
This is working correctly.

Now, I want to do this while the screen is off.
For some reason I only get 2 sensor updates per second, regardless of the SENSOR_DELAY.
I suspect this has something to do with Android saving its power. But I need a higher frequency to accurately read the sensor data.

Before I turn to a wake lock, I'd like to know if it's possible to override this "forced" frequency reduction and wether or not this is a device dependent issue. I need it to remain at a higher update frequency, even when the screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, but do you get more updates using SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST ? Then plug something like this into onSensorChanged():

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_)
    {
    long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (actualTime - lastUpdate > 63)
        {
        lastUpdate = actualTime;
        // update
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST doesn't change the interval when the screen is turned off. It falls back to about 2 updates per second, regardless of what sensor delay I use. Do you think this is device a specific occasion?

Comment: I don't know. Never used sensors with device sleeping. Guess it's time to read SensorListener docs

Comment: Maybe you could use a partial wake lock. I don't know what you're trying to do exactly. Maybe a BroadcastReceiver would work?

Comment: I'm trying to make an impact detector. However, the problem isn't how i would do it. I actually just need to know if it's possible to disable the interval decrement. I couldn't find it by googling, SO is my last resort haha

Answer (score 0):

The sensor delay values are mere recommendations (or at least they were around Android 4.0/4.1). Depending on the implementation, sensors may deliver events faster than requested. This is at the discretion of the driver and behavior may vary from device model to device model.

Why do you want to limit the event delivery rate of the sensor? If you are doing complex processing in the background and want to reduce load on the processor, consider the following approach: when you receive and process an event, record its timestamp. When the next event arrives, calculate the difference between its timestamp and the previously stored one. Process the event only if the timestamp difference is at least as big as your threshold. While this will not reduce the event delivery rate, it will reduce processing time as only one in n events gets processed.

Comment: Thanks for the response :). But this is not what I was looking for. I rephrased my original question to try and clearify what i actually mean.